# AC-DC Adaptor flashes on & off

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, dc

i have bought an ac-dc adaptor to power my mini-water pump. 
When i give power to the pump it start & goes off immediately and it's repeating like that till i plug it off. Adaptors LED is also blinking when this happens. It's like short circuit, or maybe the pump needs more power than the adaptor can handle and shuts off?

The pump is not faulty, i have tested it with another power supply (12v 0.3A) and i use the correct positive & negative terminals. 
I've also tested the adaptor with a multimeter and shows the correct voltage (The adaptor behaves normal and led does not blinking while testing it with multimeter).

My pump needs 12vdc & ~0-3A.
My adaptor is ac-dc 12v 3A

Can some1 help me? Tomorrow i'm travelling and i must make sure the pump will work at any time while i'm missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like hiccup current limiting. Use a larger adapter.

Comment: Can i modify it and remove the limit? The pump only draws 3A max at the start, so it may not be dangerous.

Comment: Is that 0-3A or 0.3A...?

Comment: @Majenko pump needs 0 to 3A, specifically 3A at start and then needs about 1A while working.

Comment: If op has a 3 Amp supply for a 300 milliamp load, is not the capacity of the supply in question.  It might be bad.

Comment: You listed that you tested it with "(12v 0.3A)", is that correct? How could the pump run correctly with that if it needs 3A (or even 1A).

Comment: If the new adapter is sensitive to the initial current drain at pump turn on you might try placing a fairly large capacitor at the input terminals (just ahead of the pump turn on switch).  That may help reduce the initial current pulse that the adapter is trying to supply.

Comment: @Nedd correct, i really don't know, maybe it's running barely and stresses the adapter while trying to drain current as much as possible.

Comment: @Nedd also my previous adapter was 12v 1A and it was working well, but its dead now. I could try to use a capacitor but i dont have any atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adapter is not powerful enough. During start-up, many electrical motors (such as the one inside the pump) require higher current. Your adapter cannot provide it, and thus enters the 'overload' condition.

Depending on how your pump works, you might be able to help the adapter by adding a LARGE capacitor - at least 20000 uF (and at least 20 volt). You want to do the following:

- Connect capacitor to power supply (make sure to observe the polarity)
- Plug in the power supply and wait for a few seconds to let capacitor charge
- Connect pump to the capacitor

The capacitor may help to provide initial surge of current to get the pump going. If you only see pump twitch a bit, but not start, then the capacitor is not big enough.

The big problem with that is that if pump stops for some reason, it would not be able to re-start. So I recommend just getting a bigger power supply.

Comment: In your first bullet, I think you want to "observe the Polarity".

Answer (score 1):

Could be quite the opposite of too less power.

I got an old 12V power supply for halogene bulbs with 80W. When I replace all 4 bulbs with 4 LED bulbs (now 24 W in total), the LED bulbs run normal initially and then start blinking synchronously after a while at about 2Hz. If I replace any LED by a halogene bulb (now 38W in total) there is no blinking anymore. I cannot find the page where I read it, but too less power consumption can cause this problem (in old power suppies) and it fits exactly with what you write: the pump ran originally on a 1A supply.You have the problem since you switched to a 3A supply and you can run the pump even with just an 0.3 A supply. So you are rather overpowered than underpowered.

If the capacitor (as theamk suggested... adding a capacitor would also have been my first guess on how to fix it) does not work, just try to add an additional load parallel e.g. a 20W halogene bulb. That then draws 1.67A and you are left with 1.33A, which is quite similar to your previous supply.